# Append to an existing file in a new line

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I want to write some texts in a new line  into an existing file.I tried following code but failed,Can any one suggest how can I append to file in a new row.

```
private void writeIntoFile1(String str) {
    try {
        fc=(FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/SpeedScence/MaillLog.txt");
        OutputStream os = fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize());
        os.write(str.getBytes());
        os.close();
        fc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and calling

```
writeIntoFile1("aaaaaaaaa");
writeIntoFile1("bbbbbb");
```

Its successfully writing to the file I simulated(SDCard) but its appears in the same line.
How can I write "bbbbbb" to new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\n`) after writing the string.

```
private void writeIntoFile1(String str) {
    try {
        fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/SpeedScence/MaillLog.txt");
        OutputStream os = fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize());
        os.write(str.getBytes());
        os.write("\n".getBytes());
        os.close();
        fc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**N.B.** a [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) is generally better-suited for printing text, though I'm not familiar enough with the BlackBerry API to know if it's possible to use a `PrintStream` at all. With a `PrintStream` you'd just use [`println()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29):

```
private void writeIntoFile1(String str) {
    try {
        fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/SpeedScence/MaillLog.txt");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize()));
        ps.println(str.getBytes());
        ps.close();
        fc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Matt Ball, Still I have the same problem

Comment: @Jisson I'm not familiar with the platform - you might need to use `\r\n` instead of `\n` for it to appear properly.

Comment: BlackBerry does support PrintStream. http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: @Swati: thanks. I took a glance at the `FileConnection` interface but didn't see any way to get a `PrintStream` instead of a vanilla `OutputStream`, so I wasn't sure if it would work in this specific case.

Comment: You can create the PrintStream by just passing it the OutputStream. i.e. PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(outputStream);

Comment: @Swati: d'oh, of course! I'll update my answer. Thanks again.